# Get Property of Interface

Tags: javascript, typescript

I try to use the [HLTV API](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hltv) and get the Upcoming Matches. To get them I would use:

```
HLTV.getMatches().then((res) => {
  /* ... */
})
```

which has a schema for upcoming matches:

```
export interface UpcomingMatch {
  readonly id: number
  readonly team1?: Team
  readonly team2?: Team
  readonly date?: number
  readonly format?: string
  readonly event?: Event
  readonly map?: MapSlug
  readonly title?: string
  readonly live: boolean
  readonly stars: number
}
```

For example to get a Team Rank I would do

```
HLTV.HLTV.getTeam ({id: 7532}).then( res => {
    console.log(res.rank);
})
```

How do I access e.g. the 'live' bool or some other property of the UpcomingMatch interface? I am still quite new to JavaScript or TypeScript in this case and could not find out how to google this question to find a fitting answer.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: just like the `rank` one too, by `res.live` or `rest.id` inside of your Promise Handler (inside the `then`)
You can probably easy see it, if u just print out the object instead of the variable `console.log(res)`

Comment: It helped a lot to know that I can just print out the whole "res" things so I saw the properties and did find out it was an array. Thanks a lot!